# how to send xml in request for jms point to point, jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter and as per the client requirement I need to send request to jms queue using point to point but the problem is the request would be through xml.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function to read the .xml file from your local or network drive right in the "Content" section of the JMS P2P Sampler

[image: JMS P2P FileToString]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) guide for more detailed information.